# Android: call onTouch event of parentview in onLongclick of childview

Tags: android, gesture, onlongclicklistener

So I have two overlaying views in a relative layout one on another. Requirement is to call touch event (to apply gestures) of second view after long click of first view.
Really messed up with touch and click events. if anyone can give a better solution.

Here's my code:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        MainActivity.this.event= event;
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
above = (Button) findViewById(R.id.above);
above.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

below = (Button) findViewById(R.id.below);
below.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.d("long", "click");
        //call on down of above here and set visibility gone of below
        return true;
    }
});
```

I have also tried dispatchtouchevent(event); but which event has to be dispatched from here?

MyGestureDetector class is:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.e("action", "down");
             //for applying scroll gestures onto it
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you using gesture here...

Comment: i want gestures on below button; to create animation for cancelling and continuing like in fb messenger while creating video. that is on single click photo is clicked, and on long press video is recording and gestures are there to cancel recording, on swiping left/right

Comment: could you add screenshot

Comment: seeing the fb messenger app in android would give the actual idea  than screenshots. please if u can check it.